# How do I get readline to return the fields of a Class?

Tags: c#, class, c#-6.0, console.readline

I am very new/ a beginner to coding. I'm using c# 6.0 in Microsoft Visual studio 2022.

I'm trying to create some sort of search function, but perhaps there is a better way to do it.

I created a class(didn't include all of the code bc of space) and gave it

```
    public void Attributes()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(affinity + ", " + aoe + ", " + effect + ", " + pointOfOrigin);
    }
```

and assigned variables in the main program/code like this

```
Spell FireBall = new Spell("Fire", "Sphere", "Explosion", "Thrown");
```

What I want to happen is to type the spell name(ex: Fireball) and then have it return the: Fire, Sphere, Explosion, Thrown.

I know that if you type FireBall.Attributes(); it will return the attributes, but I cannot figure out how to take user input to call the attributes. My first guess is that it has something to do with Console.ReadLine and assigning a variable to it but everything I've tried just turned errors.

As I said I'm a beginner and any help is much appreciated. I also apologize if I'm not being specific enough or used the wrong terms, as I'm still learning all of the vocabulary for the different stuff. I'm having a lot of fun learning, so please be nice.

Comment: "My first guess is that it has something to do with Console.ReadLine and assigning a variable to it but everything I've tried just turned errors."  That is a valid approach, and showing that code and describing the errors you got would make your question answerable.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, what you're trying to do is have the user input a keyword (a name in this instance) and return an object associated with that name, then print its attributes (this part you've already done by creating the `Attrbiutes()` method).

There are two main ways of doing this, by reflection (hard, slow, ridiculous), and by a dictionary (easy, FAST, made for this).

I will not get into the reflection method, as it requires a deep understanding of the language that I cannot give you in a Stackoverflow answer.

---

Here's the Dictionary method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//=== Spell class, this obviously isn't yours I'm just using this as an example
public class Spell {
    string affinity, aoe, effect, pointOfOrigin;
    
    public Spell(string affinity, string aoe, string effect, string pointOfOrigin) {
        this.affinity = affinity;
        this.aoe = aoe;
        this.effect = effect;
        this.pointOfOrigin = pointOfOrigin; 
    }
    
    public void Attributes()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(affinity + ", " + aoe + ", " + effect + ", " + pointOfOrigin);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //=== Create a dictionary of type Dictionary<string, Spell>. This means the dictionary has a string key and a Spell value for that key.
        Dictionary<string, Spell> Spells = new Dictionary<string, Spell>();
        
        //=== Add items to the dictionary, instead of setting a variable with its name, set the key to its name.
        // In this instance we're using names that are lowercase so we can do a case-insensitive search
        Spells["fireball"] = new Spell("Fire", "Sphere", "Explosion", "Thrown");
        
        Spells["freeze"] = new Spell("Ice", "Sphere", "Freeze", "Thrown");
        
        //=== Now here's where we ask the user what spell they'd like to print
        string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower(); //=== Here we trim (remove whitespace from the start and end) and convert the input to lowercase.
        
        //=== Then we search for the spell in the dictionary
        if(Spells.ContainsKey(input)) {
            //=== If we get here, we found the spell
            Spell spell = Spells[input];
            
            //=== Print its attributes
            spell.Attributes();
        } else {
            //=== The spell was not found
            Console.WriteLine("Spell not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iB8w3a

Enter your input in the bottom, then press enter input it.
[image: Searching for Fireball]
[image: Search found Fireball]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print out an object properties, You can use GetProperties() method. See if this example helps You. Ps: Result is the Spell object for You.

```
  var obj = new Result()
            {
                displayName = "Display Name",
                id = "1234",
                name = "Name",
                slug = "",
                 imageUrl = "url"
            };
            var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(p.Name + ", " + p.GetValue(obj, null));
            }
            Console.Write( sb.ToString());
```

[image]